# Compiling a program for user mode Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, user-mode-linux

I've just implemented a "pseudo" device driver and want to test it. What can I do as a test is just:

```
echo "something"> /dev/mydev
cat /dev/mydev
```

My driver supports more advanced functionality and I implemented a test program to test these functionaries. However I'm not able to run it on UML (Error: Floating point exception). I believe there is a "special" way of compiling user programs for UML?

Could you please give a starting point for this? How should I compile the test program?

p.s. Testing program is very simple and above error is not caused by the bug in the program.
p.p.s. For compiling the module I had ready Makefile, so it was easy :)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Both host and UML kernels are of same version 2.6.35

EDIT: I believe I need to show kernel source directory, plus some compiler options, also something like ARCH=um?

EDIT: Currently I'm compiling without any options. gcc test.c. Even the "Hello world" program is not working on the UML. Maybe i've to change something on UML compilation?

Comment: Retagged `uml`->`user-mode-linux`, the tag `uml` is for the Unified Modelling Language.

Comment: What makes you think the problem is with the method of compilation for User-Mode Linux rather than simply a bug in your code?

Comment: The code is very simple. It's just open, write/read, close. And it's working in my host OS. (on different file)

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you put your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the problem is found (thanks to my classmates and professor):

the glibc versions of the compile environment should match with UML. So compiling
--static option solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to read/write from/to your device, you have to implement, and then use on your program, at least the system calls `open()`, `read()`, `write()` and `close()`, like any other device on you Linux. For the example you gave, your program would be something like this (syntax might contain some errors):

```
char* string = "something";
char* result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(string) + 1);

int fd = open("/dev/mydev", O_RDWR);

write(fd, "something", strlen(string));

read(fd, result, strlen(string));
printf("result = %s\n", result);

close(fd);
```

Comment: I've already implemented this kind of test program. But my original question is how to compile it in order to run on UML. Normal compiling with gcc -ansi test.c is not working. I believe I need to show kernel source, plus some options plus ARCH=um somewhere.

Comment: @user502515: despite it is not necessary, it is good in order to know exactly what you are returning from the `malloc`; this is more from the developer point of view than a problem for the compiler (for C memory is memory, I know).